# First login never works

Tags: boot, login, password, 21.10

I've recently installed Ubuntu 21.10 onto my laptop and my desktop. I've been noticing a weird bug and I need to know if it's just me or not.

After booting( or recovery from hibernation) when I get to the login screen, and try to login into my account, the first login never succeeds. I put the password in correctly, hit login, and I get the spinning wheel thing for an extended period of time.

The usual way to resolve this is to type in the password, hit enter, hit escape, type in the password again and hit enter. I've been questioning my sanity so I've triple checked that the password IS correct on the first entry.

Is this just me? I'm seeing it on both machines.

Comment: Can you make a gif/video of it to show how it isn't working, In my case, it is working correctly

Comment: something in /var/crash? `ls -al /var/crash`

Comment: Nothing in /var/crash. I'll also try record something when I reboot (kinda busy with work now)

Comment: How do you get to the login screen -- mouse click or Enter?  Do you have multiple choices for users? Try typing delete (backspace) or ^u to clean out anything in the text field and then the password .

Comment: So last night I changed my password to be something I'd be happy to stick on a gif, rebooted and logged in first time... I'm choosing to believe that this was fixed in an update rather than I can't type my password, even with extreme checking...

Answer (score 0):

So last night I changed my password to be something I'd be happy to stick on a gif, rebooted and logged in first time... I'm choosing to believe that this was fixed in an update rather than I can't type my password, even with extreme checking...